# Strange circular structures found on a photo from Mars rover Curiosity at Dingo Gap

Tags: structural-geology, mars

What are all these gaps / circular structures found on a photo taken by Mars rover Curiosity at Dingo Gap? Have a look at [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLWZ5.png) I made to see what gaps I mean.

[image: dingo gap with explanation]
(I know the quick paint job looks terrible)

As you can see on the image I marked the area green where I found all these strange gaps. On the left I placed a zoomed view of the gaps, where I highlighted one.

You can find the [original picture on nasa.gov](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/pia17766-figa_mastcam-sol526-wb-scalebars_0.jpg). Here is the [accompanying article](https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/msl/pia17766/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no circles, it is an image artifact. [Here is another picture from Dingo Gap](http://planetary.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/4-mars/2014/20140131_0528ML_panorama_valley-beyond-dingo-gap.jpg) that shows nothing at the exact same position.

Your mind is a well-trained pattern-matching machine that makes up patterns even when they are not actually there.
In other words *don't jump to conclusions*. You are claiming that there are actual structures, which is one step too 'far'.

(Credit: Emily Lakdawallah [blog post](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2014/01311220-beautiful-view-into-dingo-gap-curiosity-528.html))